# How to get User ID when using Basic Auth and Session plugins are enabled in Kong?

Tags: kong, kong-plugin, kong-ingress

I'm currently using Kong API gateway. After using logging in and retrieving a session. The username is not forwarded to the backend service. How do I get the username from the session token provided by Kong?

plugins:

- name: basic-auth
  service: login-service
  config:
  hide_credentials: true
- name: session
  service: login-service
  config:
  secret: opensesame
  cookie_samesite: Lax

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the token while logging in, you can add the username in the token payload. So once you are on the backend with the token you can decrypt it and fetch the username from payload itself.